# open a details of the food in another activity with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm trying to create a a resturant apk which it has a menu inside this menu you chose what kinda food you want lets say if you want a pizza and when you press pizza it will open another menu with different kind of pizza  and when press the pizza that i want  it should take you to another activity and show you the details of the pizza but its not showing me and i don't know what is the problem

this is my food list activity

```
package com.example.median1.demo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class FoodLIst extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference foodList;

    String categoryId;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food,FoodViewHolder>adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_list);
        //firebase

        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        foodList= database.getReference("Foods");
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_food);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        //get food list intent
           if(getIntent()!=null){

           categoryId=getIntent().getStringExtra("CategoryId");
           if(!categoryId.isEmpty()&& categoryId!=null){

               loadListFood(categoryId);
           }

           }
    }

    private void loadListFood(String categoryId) {

        adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(Food.class,
                R.layout.food_item,
                FoodViewHolder.class,
                foodList.orderByChild("MenuId").equalTo(categoryId)) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(FoodViewHolder viewHolder, Food model, int position) {
              viewHolder.food_name.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.food_image);
                final Food local=model;
                viewHolder.setItemClicklistener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        // start new activity for the food destails
                        Intent foodDetails=new Intent(FoodLIst.this,FoodDetail.class);
                        foodDetails.putExtra("FoodId",adapter.getRef(position).getKey()); //send foood id to new activity
                        startActivity(foodDetails);
                    }
                });


            }
        };
        //set adapter
        Log.d("TAG",""+adapter.getItemCount());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

and this is my food details activity

```
package com.example.median1.demo;

import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;

public class FoodDetail extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView food_name,food_price,food_description;
    ImageView food_image;
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
    FloatingActionButton btnCart;
    ElegantNumberButton numberButton;
    String foodId="";
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference foods;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_detail);

        //firebase
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        foods=database.getReference("Foods");


        //int View
        numberButton=(ElegantNumberButton)findViewById(R.id.number_button);
        btnCart=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCart);
        food_description=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_description2);
        food_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_name);
        food_price=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_price);
        food_image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_food);
        collapsingToolbarLayout=(CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppbar);


        //get food id from the intent
        if(getIntent()!=null)
            foodId=getIntent().getStringExtra("FoodId");

        if(foodId.isEmpty()){

            getDetailFood(foodId);
        }

    }

    private void getDetailFood(String foodId) {

        foods.child(foodId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Food food=dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);
                //set image
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(food.getImage()).into(food_image);

                collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(food.getName());

                food_price.setText(food.getPrice());

                food_name.setText(food.getName());

                food_description.setText(food.getDescription());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the food class for the food details where i retrieve all the childs from the firebase

```
package com.example.median1.demo;

/**
 * Created by median1 on 11/5/2017.
 */

public class Food {
    private String Name,Image,Description,Price,Discount,MenuId;

    public Food() {
    }

    public Food(String name, String image, String description, String price, String discount, String menuId) {
        Name = name;
        Image = image;
        Description = description;
        Price = price;
        Discount = discount;
        MenuId = menuId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        Image = image;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        Price = price;
    }

    public String getDiscount() {
        return Discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(String discount) {
        Discount = discount;
    }

    public String getMenuId() {
        return MenuId;
    }

    public void setMenuId(String menuId) {
        MenuId = menuId;
    }
}
```

and this is the xml of the food details
i dont know if its important

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.median1.demo.FoodDetail">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        >
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="#0e0d0e"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_food"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"


                    />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:title="food name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"


                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCart"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"

        />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/food_name"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:text="Food name "
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                       <LinearLayout
                           android:id="@+id/layout_price"
                           android:orientation="horizontal"
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                           <ImageView
                               android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp"
                               android:layout_width="0dp"
                               android:layout_weight="1"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                           <TextView
                               android:id="@+id/food_price"
                               android:text="1,000 "
                               android:textSize="18sp"
                               android:textStyle="bold"
                               android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                               android:layout_width="0dp"
                               android:layout_weight="9"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



                       </LinearLayout>

                    <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"

                        android:id="@+id/number_button"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                        app:textSize="8sp"
                        app:backGroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        app:initialNumber="1"
                        app:finalNumber="20"

                        />

                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/food_description2"
               android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
               android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
               android:padding="12dp"
               android:text="description"
               android:textColor="@android:color/black"
               android:textSize="14sp"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




        </LinearLayout>



    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Firebase database

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can't you see the error on logcat or run? i think the error is here:

```
//get food id from the intent
    if(getIntent()!=null)
        foodId=getIntent().getStringExtra("FoodId");

    if(foodId.isEmpty()){

        getDetailFood(foodId);
    }
}
```

or here

```
//get food list intent
       if(getIntent()!=null){

       categoryId=getIntent().getStringExtra("CategoryId");
       if(!categoryId.isEmpty()&& categoryId!=null){

           loadListFood(categoryId);
       }

       }
}
```

maybe check run when you click and the problem happens to see where is the problem.. you may get a null string

EDITED: i made the same app got the same problem with you and on my run its saying the problem is here `if(!categoryId.isEmpty()&& categoryId!=null`